What should I do if I forgot to perform a prayer?
I was on my way to school for an exam, and on the way I realized that in my rush to get to school on time, I forgot to observe my morning prayer. What should I do.

Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Isalm. To learn more about our suite and model consider takin the [tour] and checking our [help]. As to your inquiry since you remembered it you must perform it as soon as possible check also questions with the tag [tag:salat-qada].

Perform it now that you remember, as a Qada.

من نسي صلاة فليصل إذا ذكرها، لا كفارة لها إلا ذلك
If anyone forgets a prayer he should pray that prayer when he remembers it. There is no expiation except that.
— Bukhari 597

